# How to put page in tabItem, if the page is in another folder?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I want to use a tabControl for a menu, but how can I associate the tabItems with pages in another folder?

```
 <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="TabItem">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="TabItem">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>\
```

This is the disposition of my folders:

[image]

My tabControl is in StudentWindow, and I want that one of the tabs open the page "CreateProposal", how can I do this?

Comment: Using xml namespaces in the XAML.  Take a look at the top of any XAML page.  See all the namespace declarations?  That's how they refer to objects in other namespaces.  You should probably invest the time in reading a good WPF tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Add a [XAML namespace declaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/xaml-namespaces-and-namespace-mapping-for-wpf-xaml?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) for the namespace of your `CreateProposal` class:

```
<TabItem Header="TabItem"
         xmlns:SecundaryPages="clr-namespace:WpfApp1.Pages.SecundaryPages">
    <SecundaryPages:CreateProposal />
</TabItem>
```

The above sample markup assumes that `CreateProposal` is defined in a namespace like this:

```
namespace WpfApp1.Pages.SecundaryPages
{
    public partial class CreateProposal : Page
    ...
```

Replace "WpfApp1" with the actual name of yours.

Comment: @DiegoGamboa: Did you try this or what happened?